# How can I move text to the next line if it exceeds the screen's width in Corona?

Tags: text, lua, screen, coronasdk

I want text to be continued to the below line automatically if it exceeds the width of the screen. How can I do that?

For example this one is exceeding in Android screen and I want it to be seen in the screen fully.

```
local str=display.newText("HOSGELDINIZ",50,200,nil,70)
```

Comment: Post the awnser yourself and accept it, so people see this has a awnser :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. In order to avoid exceeding, we need to add two more parameters which limits the text area.

Just like that:

```
 local str=display.newText("HOSGELDINIZ",50,200,150,150,nil,70)
```

After height and width positions, we add width and height of text area so it'll wrap without exceeding screen.

I hope that'll be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, texting multi-lines text with Corona is done within [options](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newText.html).
Here is a simple example :

```
display.newText({
        parent   = myParent,
        text     = "This is a long enough text to be on two lines",  
        width    = display.contentWidth*0.6,  
        height   = display.contentHeight*0.25,  
        x        = display.contentWidth*0.5,
        y        = display.contentHeight*0.5,
        fontSize = 24,
        align    = "center",
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to display single string of text on a new line you can use the following method.

```
local displayStr=display.newText(“this sample text can be split with \nto next line “, x, y, native.systemFont, fontSize)
```

[Notice how the ‘\n’ is used in the text to split the string]